# Should I pass objects or normal data into views?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

I'm building a timeline similar to Facebook's...with different types of posts, all sorts of data involved with each, but still highly templatized.

I am wondering if it's better to pass large multidimensional arrays into each sub-view (each item on the timeline), or if it's better to simply pass objects in (such as a "user" object), so that the sub view can use the functions of the object?

Is one more flexible than the other, and does anybody know how Facebook handles this?

Comment: "is one more flexible than the other" - arrays are iteratable, and countable. if you don't need that functionality, then you should most likely be using an object instead.

Comment: @dqhendricks Objects can very easily become iterable and countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you how facebook handles this, but normally objects are generally more flexible.

You can just echo them by using the [`__toString` function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) for example. If all objects that get passed into view are automatically decorated, this can be extremely flexible.

They can behave like arrays, if you use the [`ArrayAccess` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).

Generally: Objects are just more dynamical than arrays which are static, so objects are more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion arrays are bad idea. Many frameworks passes objects to views, but there are also ones which puts into view arrays (cakePHP for example).

I worked with cake and working with "arrayed" data in views was nightmare

```
$data['blah']['bleh']['bluh']['puh']['some_other_long_array_key_for_difference']['and']['so']['on']['fuuuuuu']
```

Use objects, they are for simplify our lifes ;]